# What is the value of q in the CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The cumulative distribution function of X is given by

{F(x) =

**0** if **x < 1**,

**0.1** if **1 ≤ x < 2**,

**0.4** if **2 ≤ x < 3**,

**0.6** if **3 ≤ x < 4**,

**q** if **4 ≤ x < 5**,

**0.9** if **5 ≤ x < 6,**

**1** if **x ≥ 6**}

You are also told that P(**4 < X^2 ≤ 16**) = **0.4**

What is the value of **q**?

I have the answer as **P(4 < X^2 ≤ 16) = P(2 < X ≤ 4) = P(X = 3) + P(X = 4) = 0.2 + q − 0.6 = q − 0.4**

Hence **q = 0.8**

Can someone explain why this is the answer to me? I keep thinking that **P(X=3) = 0.6** and **P(X=4) = q** so **0.6 + q = 0.4** but this answer doesn't mathematically make sense, I know.

Comment: Instead, think $P(X \le 3) = 0.6.$

Comment: are you given the support of $X$? Because it seems strange to define the CDF in that way if it's a discrete variable taking values in $1, 2, \dots 6$. If it doesn't have that support, however, then the solution is wrong.